# Unknown NSDate format

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following string to convert to NSDate:

2011-04-27 20:50:09.000002.

I have the following code for the dateformatter:

```
  [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

but I'm unsure of what to put after the seconds.

Keep in mind, I have multiple of these strings, with different numbers at the back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date format strings in OS 10.6 (and, I believe, in iOS4+) are based on the Unicode spec TR35-10 : [have a look at their date formatting strings](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

What you need in this case is *fractional seconds*: symbol S. Something like...

```
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
```